# ¿Alguna alternativa para req.files en NodeJS v0.12.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodejs

Necesito subir un archivo `CSV` para posteriormente guardarlo en la base de datos, esto con [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) y [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs), pero debido a restricciones del proyecto estamos usando `NodeJS v0.12.5` y no soporta `req.files`

¿Saben alguna alternativa o workaround para hacer esto mismo?

Por cuestiones de confidencialidad solo puedo poner parte del código:

```
var Q = require('q');
var fs = require('fs');
var Joi = require('joi');
var parse = require('csv-parse');
var uploadModel = require('./upload.model');
var oemController = require('../oem/oem.controller');
exports.oemUpload = function(req, res) {
    var quote_number = req.params.quote_number;
    var files = req.files; // our node version is too old, it doesn't have req.files 
    console.log(files); 
    res.send('TODO'); 
};
```

El error en consola es: `req.files is undefined.` Probando en otro equipo con Node4 esto no pasa.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, estas usando express? que version?

Comment: Usando express 4.0.0

Comment: Podrias postear lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) que te permite subir archivos, soporta multi-part y funciona desde la version v0.8.0. Ademas tiene una licencia permisiva.

Ejemplo:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');

app.use(busboy()); 

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        console.log("Subiendo: " + filename); 
        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/files/' + filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on('close', function () {
            res.send(200); // esto envia el 200 ok cuando sube todo el file
            // pero podrias usar un redirect o lo que necesites    
            // ej: req.redirect(req.header('Referer') || '/')   
        });
    });
});
```

Por cierto, en la pagina de [expressjs/body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) es una de las opciones recomendadas para subir archivos. Junto con [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-multiparty#readme), 
[formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable#readme) y [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer#readme)

Comment: Gracias la voy a probar.

Answer (score 1):

Agregando a la [respuesta de @rnrneverdies](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3554/2224) yo prefiero usar multer porque es mas sencillo y se adapta mejor a la filosofía de los `middlewares` de Express ademas de ser muy configurable hace que tus rutas o controladores sean mas limpios y solo tengan que ocuparse de la lógica de tu aplicación. El módulo [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) usa [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) internamente así que dependiendo de tus necesidades puede simplificar mucho el manejo de ficheros.

Aqui te va un ejemplo:

```
var multer = require('multer');

var uploadConfig = multer({ dest: 'files/' });

var uploadConfig2 = multer({ dest: 'uploads/', limits: { fieldSize: 5000000} });

app.post('/upload', uploadConfig.single('oem'), function(req, res, next) {
    var file = req.file;
    // Mucho mas limpio
    // El valor de lo que va aquí depende de como hayas configurado el upload en este 
    // caso un solo fichero
    console.log(file);
});

app.post('/upload2', uploadConfig2.fields([{name: 'oem1', maxCount: 1}, {name: 'oem2', maxCount: 2}]), function() {
     var files = req.files;
     // Un arreglo con como máximo 3 ficheros y un máximo de tamaño de 5MB por cada uno
     console.log(files);
});
```

Como vez en el ejemplo puedes usar los metodos de tu variable [uploadConfig.array](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#arrayfieldname-maxcount) y [uploadConfig.fields](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#fieldsfields) para cargar varios ficheros a la vez, siendo la ultima opción la más potente en cuanto a configuración se refiere. También puse un ejemplo de como puedes tener en un mismo lugar 2 configuraciones completamente diferentes, en la segunda se especifica una carpeta diferente y un tamaño máximo de 5Mb máximo para tus ficheros siendo 1Mb la configuración por defecto.

Comment: Gracias estoy probando busboy pero revisaré también multer haber como me va mejor.